# windbg will not break in on hung system(kernel debugging)

Tags: windows-xp, debugging

I have a target system that is consistently hanging. After the hang I 
get no response at all, I can't ping it, the NUM LOCK and CAPS LOCK 
keys do not toggle the associated lights on the keyboard.

I am currently attached to the system using kernel mode debugging over 
rs232. When the system hangs I am not able to break the debugger using <kbd>CTRL</kbd> - <kbd>BREAK</kbd> or Break in the menu.Is there another way for me to break into this?

Is the hang at such a low-level that I am locked out of the kernel all together?

It does not seem to me that my user mode application could cause a hang this bad, is this a correct assumption or am I missing something?

Comment: A co-worker thinks this is a problem with ACPI, so I setup the driver verifier to verify acpi.sys with all option except Low Resources. However when I do this the machine crashes with a DRIVER_VERIFIER_DETECTED_VIOLATION error but savrt.sys, part of Norton Anit Virus, is the offending driver. Doe the driver verifier enable some basic checks for ALL drivers, or is this somehow tied to acpi.

btw I am running Windows XP SP3.

Thanks